# DataFlow Worker Runtime Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I was running a dataflow job (jobid: 2018-03-13_13_21_09-13427670439683219454).

The job stopped running after 1 hour with the following error message:

```
(f38a2b0cb8c28493): Workflow failed. Causes: [...] 
(6bf57c531051aa32): A work item was attempted 4 times without success. 
Each time the worker eventually lost contact with the service. 
The work item was attempted on: [...]
```

I've successfully run the same job on different data however this data seems to be somehow different.

I didn't find any obvious error messages in the stackdriver that appear to be informative except this one:

```
Exception in worker loop: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 778, in run deferred_exception_details=deferred_exception_details) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 630, in do_work exception_details=exception_details) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py", line 175, in wrapper return fun(*args, **kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 491, in report_completion_status exception_details=exception_details) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 299, in report_status work_executor=self._work_executor) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/workerapiclient.py", line 359, in report_status self._client.projects_locations_jobs_workItems.ReportStatus(request)) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/clients/dataflow/dataflow_v1b3_client.py", line 557, in ReportStatus config, request, global_params=global_params) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 722, in _RunMethod return self.ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 728, in ProcessHttpResponse self.__ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request)) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 599, in __ProcessHttpResponse http_response, method_config=method_config, request=request) HttpBadRequestError: HttpError accessing <https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/wikidetox-viz/locations/us-central1/jobs/2018-03-13_15_14_56-7727174963497501590/workItems:reportStatus?alt=json>: response: <{'status': '400', 'content-length': '356', 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'server': 'ESF', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-control': 'private', 'date': 'Tue, 13 Mar 2018 22:48:10 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}>, content <{ "error": { "code": 400, "message": "(99f9b99d6c881f47): Failed to publish the result of the work update. Causes: (99f9b99d6c881644): Failed to update work status. Causes: (e00f9cd76af5eb): Failed to update work status., (e00f9cd76afcd5): Work \"5154713722864856696\" not leased (or the lease was lost).", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } } >
```

Is there anyway I can debug this?

**Update**

After upgrading the cloud storage package, I ran it with this job id (2018-03-13_19_26_59-7765405222195746041)

The error I got seems to be a apache beam writing error.

```
(3c513425829099bc): Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 582, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 170, in execute
    op.finish()
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 334, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.finish
    def finish(self):
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 335, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.finish
    with self.scoped_finish_state:
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 336, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.finish
    self.dofn_runner.finish()
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 411, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.finish
    self._invoke_bundle_method(self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_finish_bundle)
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 402, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._invoke_bundle_method
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 431, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
    raise new_exn, None, original_traceback
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 400, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._invoke_bundle_method
    bundle_method()
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 174, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnInvoker.invoke_finish_bundle
    def invoke_finish_bundle(self):
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 177, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnInvoker.invoke_finish_bundle
    self.output_processor.finish_bundle_outputs(
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 500, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.finish_bundle_outputs
    for result in results:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/io/iobase.py", line 969, in finish_bundle
    yield WindowedValue(self.writer.close(), window.MAX_TIMESTAMP,
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/io/filebasedsink.py", line 302, in close
    self.sink.close(self.temp_handle)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/io/filebasedsink.py", line 144, in close
    file_handle.close()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/gcsio.py", line 863, in close
    self._flush_write_buffer()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/gcsio.py", line 896, in _flush_write_buffer
    raise self.upload_thread.last_error  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
RuntimeError: BadStatusCodeError: HttpError accessing <https://www.googleapis.com/resumable/upload/storage/v1/b/wikidetox-viz-dataflow/o?uploadType=resumable&alt=json&upload_id=AEnB2UrkJEFlq2t-c9_Zpo_NuYip7Z6yFU12xq4bRtOTRtFPJ0GOhBJ9WhnuYTkR9vsbi59izn1ifO3h5-hc6oHECMD3tFLidQ&name=bakup%2Freconstruction-from-shortpages-pages-week20year2012%2Fbeam-temp-last_rev-9f8513e0273011e8803b42010a80003d%2F365af941-49ae-4867-8793-5e5858dbf048.last_rev>: response: <{'status': '503', 'content-length': '19', 'server': 'UploadServer', 'x-guploader-uploadid': 'AEnB2Ur4-2Nih8b2X2VbCFUcaKviZt7nCj9OYrZ6lfCP_ne5EegXEw5ZJayGLGwg9ix9Xdle1TcSOhFR-T6qGoc63A0zHhL2Qw', 'date': 'Wed, 14 Mar 2018 02:49:35 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'}>, content <Service Unavailable> [while running 'WriteBackInput_last_rev/Write/WriteImpl/WriteBundles/WriteBundles']
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In stackdriver, look at the "worker-startup" logs for your job. When your dataflow job fails after 1 hour, it most of the time means dataflow fails to start its workers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually HTTP errors like the python write are caused by transient things and should be retried automatically. Your job is failing because the same work item failed 4 times. So I would look for different errors in the worker logs for one of the workers that failed.

One common thing you might look for is errors like the following:

Progress reporter thread for workitem  was not able to send a successful progress report to Dataflow service during last 460 seconds. This might have been due to (1) high worker memory usage, (2) user code that prevents progress reporter thread from being scheuled appropriately, or (3) other issues related to Dataflow service. Delayed progress reports could result in the lease of current workitem being expired. If the same workitem expires multiple times, Dataflow job may fail.

This error indicates your worker is either out of memory or stalled and not able to reply to progress updates. It might be good to memory or CPU profile the worker.

Comment: "It might be good to memory or CPU profile the worker." - any links or information on how to do that?

Comment: @afaulconbridge look here https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/profiling-a-pipeline